# Nilpotent Groups Characterization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that G finite is nilpotent iff for every proper subgroup H of G, $N_G(H)  ≠  H $.

Since H is a proper subgroup of G, $Z_0(G) = {e} ⊆ H$, and G is nilpotent then there is a n such that $Z_{n-1}(G)⊆H $ and $Z_{n}(G)⊈ H $ . it is enough prove that$Z_{n}(G)⊆ N_G(H) $. Let $x \in Z_n(G)$ , so $[G,x] ⊆ Z_{n-1}(G) ⊆ H$, then for $h \in H$,

$h^{-1}xhx{-1} = [h{-1},x] \in H $, then $$h(h^{-1}xhx^{-1}) = h([h^{-1},x])$$
finally $ xhx^{-1} \in H$ then $ x \in N_G(H)$.

Is it correct?
How can i prove the other way?.

Comment: The other direction is not true in general. But it is true when $G$ is finite. To prove it for finite groups, you could use the fact that $N_G(N_G(P)) = N_G(P)$ for any Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$.

Comment: I try cnstruct a P p-subgroup Sylow and how apply you hint ?

Comment: Or alternatively use that if all proper subgroups are properly contained in their normalizers, then all subgroups are subnormal. Since normal Sylow subgroups are characteristic, this shows that all the Sylows are normal (this is essentially the same idea as the one Mikko gave, but it means you don't need to know that normalizers of Sylows are self-normalizing).

Comment: I can not prove the order way with your approx ? Can you explain me?